# Use SQL Query at DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, sql

How can i use this SQL query in C#?  I want use it in a `DataGridView`.

```
SELECT dbo.tbl_moein.[ID-Kol],dbo.tbl_moein.ID,dbo.tbl_kol.Name,dbo.tbl_moein.name,dbo.tbl_moein.tell,dbo.tbl_moein.address,dbo.tbl_moein.remain FROM dbo.tbl_kol,dbo.tbl_moein
```

Comment: What attempt have you made so far?  It sounds like you're not familiar with how to bind form controls to data, and there are many tutorials out there which cover various approaches for achieving that.  What have you tried, and in what way is it not working?

Comment: i use this for 1 table i want use 2table and get 1 field from another table ---var db = new mydataDataContext();// linq class
            var simple_query = db.tbl_users;//this is linq query
            dataGridView1.DataSource = simple_query;

Comment: Do you then call `dataGridView1.DataBind();` after that code?  Is anything returned by the query?  So far you haven't demonstrated or even described any sort of issue.  It sounds like you just need to update the query to match the logic in the query that's in the question.

Comment: No i dont use this.with this code i get data intotable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can try my code:

```
 SqlConnection sqlconnection= new SqlConnection(""); // your sqlconn

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT dbo.tbl_moein.[ID-Kol],dbo.tbl_moein.ID,dbo.tbl_kol.Name,dbo.tbl_moein.name,dbo.tbl_moein.tell,dbo.tbl_moein.address,dbo.tbl_moein.remain FROM dbo.tbl_kol,dbo.tbl_moein", sqlconnection);
            SDA.Fill(dt);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```